# client=MongoClient() syntax error using pyspark

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pymongo

I'm trying to realize analystics through Spark using Pyspark. The event, once analyzed, should be send in a Mongo database.
The python code is in the file myFile.py
However, when running this command:

```
spark-2.0.0/bin/spark-submit myFile.py
```

I have the following error:

```
client=MongoClient('localhost' , 27017)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This being said, I have tried with spaces around the "=" but it did not change a thing, I checked for unwanted spaces before the line or wrong indentation but everything looks fine. Moreover, pymongo is imported at the beginning of the file

I found this configuration online, looking on tutorials and checking in the pymongo documentation.

Can anyone help on this matter?
I apologize for any error in my English, it is not my native language.

**Edit:**
Here is the surrounding code:

```
if "User dn cn" in part2:
   usrDnCnMsg = part2.split(",")
   usrDnCnElements = list()
   for element in usrDnCnMsg:
      usrDnCnElements.append(element.split("=")[1].lstrop().rstrip()
   # sending event to DB
   client=MongoClient('localhost' , 27017)
   db = client.TEST
   found = db.user.findOne({"usrName":usrDnCnElements[0]})
   if found == None:
      result = db.user.insertOne({"usrName":usrDnCnElements[0],"usrGrp":"null"})
      result = db.usrDnCn.insertOne({"timestamp":timestamp,"usrID":db.user.findOne({"usrName":usrDnCnElements[0]})["_id"],"country":usrDnCnElements[1],"ou":usrDnCnElements[2],"dn":usrDnCnElements[3],"dn1":usrDnCnElements[4]})
   # close connection
   client.close()
```

This code is itself inside another if.

Comment: Show us more of the surrounding code; this by itself looks just fine.

Comment: `usrDnCnElements.append(element.split("=")[1].lstrop().rstrip()` - you have missing closing parenthesis (and misspelled method).

Comment: You may want to check out [MongoDB Spark Connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark) to read/write data between MongoDB and Spark. The connector has some logic to calculate split points  for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm answering my own question.

Some typing errors were in my code inducing error messages that were not explicitely designating those typing errors. Also, my pymongo installation was not correctly done.
I corrected the typing errors in my code and reinstalled pymongo and it seems to work now.